# Chain rule with a vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I'm trying to apply the chain rule to $\vec{r}=\vec{r}(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ to provide the expression for $d\vec{r}$ above. However I do not seem to be able to apply the 'tree diagram' mnemonic here and it's not like anything I have seen before.

Comment: Would it look more familiar if u_1, u_2, and u_3 were functions of t and you were calculating dr/dt?

Comment: Yes I would understand if that were the case

Comment: This way is just turning it into the language of differentials, just as for y = sin x, you can write dy = cos x dx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of differentials, let's just use the derivative.  And because $x$, $y$, and $z$ will probably look more familiar to you, let's just change the $u_1$, $u_2$, and $u_3$ to $x$, $y$, and $z$.  Then the chain says that for a function $\mathbf r = \mathbf r(x(t), y(t), z(t))$ we have:

$$\frac {d\mathbf r}{dt} = \frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial x}\frac {dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial y}\frac {dy}{dt} + \frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial z}\frac {dz}{dt}$$

Getting back the differential notation is then kinda like "multiplying" both sides by $dt$.

Comment: I don't really understand why you are allowed to let $u_1,u_2,u_3$ all become functions of $t$